# jQuery fontSize increase on Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome

This bit of code:

```
$(div).stop().animate({ 
    fontSize: "+=20%",
}, {
    duration: duration2,
    easing: "easeOutBack"
});
```

should increase font size by 20%, and it does on all browsers except Chrome, where it **decreases** font size for some reason.

Specifically the page I'm working with is: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/67774614/letters/letters.html . Type letters to drop them, then the letters should increase in font size as well as jumping and going red on mouseover. On Chrome they should (incorrectly) decrease in font size.

The problem is on line 82-90 in this script: http://tny.cz/49bc46f7

Here's a fiddle as suggested: http://jsfiddle.net/cZEzy/1/

Comment: Can you post the relevant HTML/CSS ? If you can create a [**fiddle**](http://jsFiddle.net) with the default CSS values and the relevant HTML/script that is even better as once the links you posted are dead the question is less meaningful.

Comment: Looking very quickly at the linked site, you have no initial font-size values set in your letter.css. Add some `console.log()` statements to your script to see what Chrome thinks your default font-size is. Try setting a default font-size maybe something like `1em/16px` for example. So Chrome knows from what to increase the font to `+=20%`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions and nice comment about the animations, they all helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set an initial font-size. Looking through your code the letter.css has no default font-size specified.

Using the code from `Alex Milewski`'s answer and extending on it.

Basic HTML:

```
<div id="org">Stuff1</div>
<div id="the">Stuff2</div>
```

And the basic script:

```
$('#the').animate({ 
    fontSize: "+=20%",
}, {
    duration: 2000,
    easing: "easeOutBack"
});
```

No default font-size, replicating your issue:

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jKP3G) - Issue replicated

---

Using a default font-size, similar to the below fixes the issue:

```
body{
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jKP3G/1/) - Using a default font-size

---

Comment: That fixed it, thanks. I still have no idea why Chrome would want to decrease the font size without a default font size set though.

Comment: @Arty-fishL: I'm not sure. I think it is jQuery UI 1.10 not getting the correct value from Chrome. When using `alert($("#org").css("font-size"));` jQuery does show in the first DEMO, replicating the issue, `16px` but still for some reason jQuery UI does not seem to get that value passed from Chrome. That would indicate that jQuery and jQuery UI do not use the same functions to obtain the value. Though as seen in `Alex Milewski`'s answer, when using jQuery 1.9 and latest jQuery-UI the issue is not occurring. Though I would believe giving a default font-size is good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure why this is happening in Chrome.

A simple workaround would be to define the font size as a variable and increment it manually,
then use the variable as the parameter during the animation

```
Var fontsize = $(div).css('font-size') * 1.2;
$(div).stop().animate({ 
    fontSize: fontsize,
}, {
    duration: duration2,
    easing: "easeOutBack"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking it is your CSS maybe: this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PykWe/1/) uses your code and works great in my Chrome...

```
$('#the').animate({ 
    fontSize: "+=20%",
}, {
    duration: 2000,
    easing: "easeOutBack"
});
```

Comment: -1 as OP is using jQuery 1.7 and jquery-ui 1.10 and as soon as you switch to those libraries the problem is persistent in Chrome. See the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jKP3G/) showing the issue, using OPs jQuery and jQuery UI